# How to make a backup of windows OS

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup

How to make a complete operating system backup of windows without anything missing, to switch it to a different hard drive?
A complete personal usable backup without using untrusted software, exactly like original.

Comment: have a look at this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/28501/does-it-makes-sense-to-backup-the-whole-partition-as-opposed-to-their-files

Comment: Can you define 'untrusted software'.

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask **Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on [SU].

Answer (score 0):

## [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/%20Clonezilla)

Clonezilla should help you backup your entire windows partition, which is the recommended way of backing it up. As an alternative,you should also try out the [Backup Tool inside Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/backup-and-restore) itself, as it offers far more finer control over the backup process(such as backing up user account and profiles)

The default ubuntu backup tool, [DejaDup](https://live.gnome.org/DejaDup) is an excellent tool for backing up folders, but it won't help with a complete Windows Backup. It might be useful if you want to backup your windows documents folder, for instance.